# Composing a small list with elements among some candidate elements, where the inclusion of each element depends on an independent predicate?

Tags: clojure

Say I want to return a collection containing some subset of [1 2 3 4].  Whether 1 is included depends on w?, whether 2 is included depends on x?, 3 on y?, 4 on z?.

If I did

```
[(if (w?) 1) (if (x?) 2) (if (y?) 3) (if (z?) 4)]
```

And (x?) and (y?) evaluated to true, the others false, I'd end up with

```
[nil 2 3 nil]
```

but I want

```
[2 3]
```

Is there a canonical way to accomplish this?  It's reminiscent of a list comprehension, but not quite the same.

Thanks

EDIT:

I supposed I could create a map {1 w? 2 x? 3 y? z 4?} and then `reduce` that by either consing or not consing each key depending on whether it's value function evaluates to true, but maybe there's a better way.

Comment: or you could just filter out nils after you generate the list

Comment: `(remove nil? [nil 2 3 nil])`?

Comment: I thought of that, but what if nil is among the intentional candidate elements?  Seems unlikely, but possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do what you want:

```
(defn f [conds vs]
  (when (seq vs)
    (let [[c1 & cr] conds
          [v1 & vr] vs]
      (if c1 
        (cons v1 (f cr vr))
        (f cr vr)))))
```

Example:

```
(f [false true true false] [1 2 3 4])
=> (2 3)

(f [true true false true false true] [1 2 3 nil 4 5])
=> (1 2 nil 5)
```

Comment: Thanks, I like it.  I suppose I was hoping there'd be a more built-in or standardized way to do it since it seems like it'd be somewhat commonplace, but this aint bad.

Comment: If you don't care about losing the nils then it's easier. In most cases we want to remove nils.

Comment: Right.  If we *do* want to remove nils, is the `remove nil?` approach combined with my way of generating the list in the first way probably the best way to do it?